# JavaScript dynamic content working only on first element

Tags: javascript, html

All the HTML stuffs are generating with document.write lets say I have more than one ul elements, and in each ul are two li elements. on click first li the second one drops down where is the dynamic content. The content in every drop down depends on li element upper.

Here are some code copied from prj:

```
document.write("<div class='coolTable'> ")
    document.write("<span style='font-family:Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif;'> Round " + groupCounter + "  (" + s + " Sets - " + r + " Reps)</span>")
    document.write("<ul>")
    document.write("<li id='" + i + "' class='listPoints' onclick='dropDown(this); overlay(" + i + ");'> Exercise </li>")

    document.write("<li id='overlay'><div id='overlay16' onscroll='scrollLimit()'><p hidden id='number'> number </p><div class=new_div style='background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.73); border:0; box-shadow:none; width:100%; height:100px; overflow:hidden; margin-top:15px'> <img id='testImg2' src='C:/Users/jcournoyer/Documents/fytPics/Move 9_rough.png' alt='Exercie Picture' height='95px'> </div><div class=new_div style='background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.73); border:0; box-shadow:none; width:100%; height: 250px;  margin-top:15px' color='#FFFFFF' width='100%'><text id='exerciseName' style='color:white;font-size:110%; font-family:Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif;'> Exercise Information </text><div style='background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.73);height:200px;width:100%;overflow:auto;border:0; box-shadow:none; margin-top:10px' width='160%'><p id='description' align='left' style='font-size:85%'>Content you want the user to see goes here.</p></div></div><div style='background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.73); border:0; box-shadow:none; width:100%; height: 250px;  margin-top:30px' color='#FFFFFF'><text style='color:white;font-size:110%; font-family:Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif;'> Exercise Video </text><div style='background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.73); border:0; box-shadow:none; height:300px;  margin-top:10px'><iframe style='opacity:0.0' id='exerciseVideo' src='https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bynj5wN12K5kdmtBQnY0X0xQSVU/preview' width='90%' height='200'></iframe></div></div><div style='border:0; box-shadow:none; width:100%;margin: 10px 0; max-height: 47px;'><a href='#' onclick='likeExercise()' style='display: inline-block; max-height: 46px;'><img src='http://googledrive.com/host/0Bynj5wN12K5kR0IzWGRRUmhUb1k/FYT_Icon_Like_Grey_sq.png'  height = '45px' width='45px'  hspace='5' title='Like'></img></a><a href='#' onclick='dislikeExercise()' style='display: inline-block; max-height: 46px; margin-left: 50px;'><img src='http://googledrive.com/host/0Bynj5wN12K5kR0IzWGRRUmhUb1k/FYT_Icon_Dislike_Grey_sq.png'  height = '45px' width='45px' hspace='5' title='Dislike'></img></a><a href='#' onclick='jointPain()' style='display: inline-block; max-height: 46px; margin-left: 50px;'><img src='http://googledrive.com/host/0Bynj5wN12K5kR0IzWGRRUmhUb1k/FYT_Icon_Pain_Grey_sq.png'  height = '45px' width='45px' hspace='5' title='This one Hurts!'></img></a><a href='#' onclick='trackProgress()' style='display: inline-block; max-height: 46px; margin-left: 50px;'><img src='http://googledrive.com/host/0Bynj5wN12K5kR0IzWGRRUmhUb1k/FYT_Icon_Pencil_Grey_sq.png'  height = '45px' width='45px' hspace='5' title='Track my Progress'></img></a><a href='#' onclick='gotoCaspio()' style='display: inline-block; max-height: 46px; margin-left: 50px;'> <img src='http://googledrive.com/host/0Bynj5wN12K5kR0IzWGRRUmhUb1k/FYT_Icon_Done_Grey_sq.png'  height = '45px' width='45px'  hspace='5' title='I am done!'> </a></div></div></li>")
    document.write("</ul>")

function overlay(x) {
    el = document.getElementById("overlay");
    el2 = document.getElementById("exerciseVideo");
    el3 = document.getElementById("display-table");



    document.getElementById("exerciseName").innerHTML = Exercise[winnerChickenDinner[x]][30]
    document.getElementById("testImg2").src = "http://www.googledrive.com/host/0Bynj5wN12K5kZzlJWENRcWVobHc/" + Exercise[winnerChickenDinner[x]][60] + ".png"
    document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = s + " Sets of " + r + "</br> </br><span style='font-size:100%'> <b> Exercise Description </b> </span>" + Exercise[winnerChickenDinner[x]][62] + "</br></br><span style='font-size:100%'> <b> Tips & Tricks </b> </span> </br></br>" + Exercise[winnerChickenDinner[x]][64] + "</br></br> <span style='font-size:100%'> <b> Make It Harder </b> </span></br></br>" + Exercise[winnerChickenDinner[x]][65] + "</br></br> <span style='font-size:100%'> <b> Make It Easier </b> </span></br></br>" + Exercise[winnerChickenDinner[x]][66] 
    document.getElementById("exerciseVideo").src = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/" + Exercise[winnerChickenDinner[x]][61] + "/preview"
    document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = x
    }
```

I have around 9 if/else's so I have 9 `<ul>`s but `document.write("<li id='" + i + "' class='listPoints' onclick='dropDown(this); overlay(" + i + ");'> Exercise </li>")` `overlay(" + i + ")` is working only on first `<li>` I think the problem is mostly there. I need every `<li>` to open his overlay.

I'm not JavaScript guy, I just got this extra headache.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Yes., every time your element is created, you will be getting a new tag with `id` as a value for `i`.

Make sure that the 'i' value is changed. As any number of tags with same `id` value, can have only the first one affected, you will not see any changes now.

Make sure that you change the values of the `id` for every iteration/createElement().

For doing so, onclick of the tag, you can call a function in which the value of the variable `i` is incremented or at least changed as per your needs!

```
function dropDown(el) { 
    toggleClass(el.nextElementSibling, 'overlayOpen');
    i += 1;
}
```

You will face some problem in case your variable `i` is locally declared. You need to declate it globally.

In javaScript, any vaiable with no declaration is considered as a global variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can you write that code so I can figure out what is where?

here is the onClick function:

Comment: `function dropDown(el) {
    toggleClass(el.nextElementSibling, 'overlayOpen');
    
  }`

Comment: Not sure how I can declare global variable `i` Can you please update?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp This link will be useful for you! @Gabriel747